# Is there any way to use oversized okra?

Tags: culinary-uses, okra

I accidentally let some of my okra grow much too large.  It's about six inches long, and I've heard that it's inedible at this size--per [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SZmXlYsjGA) it should be 2 1/2" to 3".

Is there any way to cook these or are they really best sent to the compost bin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience (I'm Texan, I've seen my share of okra), 2.5-3" is pretty small, and 6" is on the big side but I wouldn't expect it to be inedible. It's certainly going to be much more tender at 2.5-3"; there's no possible way it'll be too tough to eat. Larger does mean tougher, but at that size they might still be okay (for example [this source](http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/archives/parsons/vegetables/okra.html) says 4-6" is good). It looks like different varieties can have pretty different sizes - for example, this [cow's horn okra](http://sustainableseedco.com/heirloom-vegetable-seeds/l-pa/okra-heirloom-seeds/cows-horn-okra-seeds.html) is supposed to be best at 6-7" but still be good at 14"!

In any case, test the okra *you* have; no reason to choose just based on the length. Just try cutting it with a sharp knife, and if it's really hard and fibrous, you'll know. If it's borderline, any sort of long stewing method will be your best bet. You'd also want to cut it fairly thinly, so that you don't have very long fibrous strands to try to chew.

If it's really too hard to soften even like that, you might still be able to get some use out of it as a thickener but I don't think you'll ever be eating it on its own. If you want to try thickening with it, I'd cut it into bigger chunks, so that you can easily fish them out once they've done their work.

Answer (score 2):

What i do is boil over sized okra pods (cut open) in a stock pot until the water cooks down and thickens, then strain the water off, then use the water to season any vegetable or meat dish. It makes an awsum seasoning for just about everything. Another way is to just put them whole in the freezer. When you need some, take one out, cut in half and throw it in a pot of beens.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Garden. Yes I forgot to pick you up for a few times. I have had them get as large as 8 inches. Just to see if I can eat them this large I cooked a lot of them together that was 6 inches and less. I just boiled them. They were melt-in-your-mouth nothing wrong with them I do not know what species are. I will try to fry some later. the larger ones I mean. I'll let you guys know how those come out.